# NHibernate QueryOver extensibility

Tags: .net, nhibernate, lambda, queryover

Is it possible to extend QueryOver API by somehow? What I want to add is the fol

```
var criteria = QueryOver.Of<InternalAssessor>()
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Sector).HasAtLeastOneFlagSet((int)sector)
```

Where sector is bit flag enum. We had such criterion for ICriteria API and I can do

```
.Where(BitwiseRestrictions.AtLeastOneFlagSet("Sector", (int)sector))
```

But want to have strongly typed way of doing it. Are there any examples of extending QueryOver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, pretty straightforward way, how to take `IQueryOver`, search its *Underlying criteria* and append one, see https://gist.github.com/2304623

```
public static IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> WhereBitwiseRestriction<TRoot, TSubType>(
  this IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> query
  , Expression<Func<TSubType, object>> expression
  , int number)
{
  var name = ExpressionProcessor.FindMemberExpression(expression.Body);
  query.UnderlyingCriteria.Add
  (
    BitwiseRestrictions.AtLeastOneFlagSet(name, number)
  );
  return query; 
}
```

And use it

```
var criteria = QueryOver.Of<InternalAssessor>()
    ...
    .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Name).IsLike(searchedName) // standard
    ...
    .WhereBitwiseRestriction(x => x.Sector, (int)sector) // custom
    ...
```

*To fulfil your request completely, we would need to introduce some man-in-the-middle object, which will hold reference to `query` and our `BitwiseRestrictions`. Another extension will immediately take it, append `number` and return query. Similar is doing the `QueryOverRestrictionBuilder` in NHibernate... but is not the above working and simple enough?*

Comment: See https://github.com/AndreasJilvero/NHibernate.Bitwise for a great solution using QueryOver (including a "has any").